# Problems with a c++ class

Tags: c++, class

I am working on this university project and I have 2-3 issues. I want to get them done 1 by 1.

My first question is about one of my getter/setter functions.

Here are the class's attributes:

I got getters and setters for each attribute of the class, and a view function that shows the attributes of a class object

```
class Game{
private: 
    string gameName;        
    float gamePrice;
    int gameNoPlatforms;
    string *gamePlatforms;
    int gameNoSitesRating;
    int *gameRatings;
    int gameSales[19];
    string gameLaunchers[5];
}
```

Those 2 are my get/set function for the atribute * string gamePlatforms:

```
void setGamePlatforms(string *newGamePlatforms, int newGameNoPlatforms) 
{
    if (this->gamePlatforms != NULL)
    {
        delete[] this->gamePlatforms;
    }
    if (newGameNoPlatforms > 0 )
    {
        this->gameNoPlatforms = newGameNoPlatforms;
        this->gamePlatforms = new string[this->gameNoPlatforms];

        for (int i = 0; i < this->gameNoPlatforms; i++)
        {
            this->gamePlatforms[i] = newGamePlatforms[i];
        }
    }
    else cout << "The number of new game platforms can't be negative. "<< endl;
}

string *getGamePlatforms()
{
    return this->gamePlatforms;
}
```

And this is the input that i tried to test on:

```
int main(){
    Game g1;                    

    int noPlatforms = 10;
    string*model = new string[noPlatforms];
    for (int i = 0; i < noPlatforms; i++)
    {
        model[i] = "Platform " + to_string(i+10);  
    }

    g1.setGamePlatforms(model, noPlatforms); //-> not working
    g1.setGamePlatforms(model, noPlatforms);
    cout << g1.getGamePlatforms();
    return 0;
}
```

And for me it is returning a weird value. I think it is an address. What have I done wrong?

Edit: the entire class:

```
class Game{
private: string gameName;       
         float gamePrice;
         int gameNoPlatforms;
         string *gamePlatforms;
         int gameNoSitesRating;
         int *gameRatings;
         int gameSales[19];
         string gameLaunchers[5];            

public:
//    Constructor1 fara parametrii pt game
    Game():gameReleaseYear(2000)
    { 
        this->gameName = "Counter-Strike";

        this->gamePrice = 20;
        this->gameNoPlatforms = 10;
        this->gamePlatforms = new string[this->gameNoPlatforms];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->gameNoPlatforms; i++)
        {
            this->gamePlatforms[i] = "Platform" + to_string(i+1);
        }
        this->gameNoSitesRating = 5;
        this->gameRatings = new int[this->gameNoSitesRating];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->gameNoSitesRating; i++)
            this->gameRatings[i] = i + 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
        {
            this->gameSales[i] = i + 2;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            this->gameLaunchers[i] = "Launcher" + to_string(i);
        }

        this->noGames++; //incrementare nr games
    }
//  Constructor cu parametrii pt game
    Game(string gameNameP, float gamePriceP, int gameNoPlatformsP, string *gamePlatformsP, int gameNoSitesRatingP, int *gameRatingsP, int gameSalesP[19], string gameLaunchersP[5]) :gameReleaseYear(2005)
    {
        this->gameName = gameNameP;
        this->gamePrice = gamePriceP;
        this->gameNoPlatforms = gameNoPlatformsP;
        this->gamePlatforms = new string[this->gameNoPlatforms];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->gameNoPlatforms; i++)
        {
            gamePlatforms[i] = gamePlatformsP[i];
        }
        this->gameNoSitesRating = gameNoSitesRatingP;
        this->gameRatings = new int[this->gameNoSitesRating];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->gameNoSitesRating; i++)
        {
            gameRatings[i] = gameRatingsP[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
        {
            gameSales[i] = gameSalesP[i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            gameLaunchers[i] = gameLaunchersP[i];
        }
    }

// Destructor pt game
    ~Game()
    {
        if (this->gamePlatforms != NULL)
            delete[] this->gamePlatforms;
        if (this->gameRatings != NULL)
            delete[] this->gameRatings;

        noGames--; // decrementare nr games

    }

// Functie de afisare pentru game
    void view()
    {
        cout << "For the game: " <<' '<<  this->gameName << " we have the following details: " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The release year for the game was: " << this->gameReleaseYear << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The game is sold at a full price of: " << this->gamePrice << " euroes" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The number of sites that are rating this game is: " << this -> gameNoSitesRating << " and the ratings are: " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < this->gameNoSitesRating; i++)
        {   if(this->gameRatings[i]+i >10)
            cout << "The no " << i + 1 << " site is rating the game as " << 10 << " stars out of 10 " << endl;
            else
            cout << "The no " << i+1 << " site is rating the game as " << this->gameRatings[i] << " stars out of 10 " << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The sales of the game from the release year since now are: " << endl;
        for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++)
        {
            cout << "For the year " << i << " the sales estimate at " << gameSales[i] << " millions" << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "The launchers that support the game are: " << endl;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cout << gameLaunchers[i] << ' ' << endl;
        }
        cout << "The game is currently running on " << this->gameNoPlatforms << " number of platforms, and those platforms are: " << endl;
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < this->gameNoPlatforms; i++)
        {
            cout << this->gamePlatforms[i] << endl;
        }
    }

// functiile accesor getters


    string getGameName()
    {
        return this->gameName;
    }
    float getGamePrice()
    {
        return this->gamePrice;
    }
    int getGameNoPlatforms()
    {
        return this->gameNoPlatforms;
    }
    int getNoSitesRating()
    {
        return this->gameNoSitesRating;
    }
    string *getGamePlatforms()
    {
        return this->gamePlatforms;
    }
    int *getGameRatings()
    {
        return this->gameRatings;
    }
    string *getGameLaunchers()
    {
        return this->gameLaunchers;
    }

//functiile accesor setters

    void setGameName(string newGameName) //testat pt input valid si invalid
    {   if(newGameName != gameName)
        this->gameName = newGameName;
    else cout << "This is the actual name of the game, no modify is required.";
    }

    void setGamePrice(float newPrice)  //testat pt input valid si invalid;
    { if(newPrice>0)
        this->gamePrice = newPrice;
    else cout << "The price can't be negative." << endl;
    }

    void setGameNoPlatforms(int newNoPlatforms)  //testat pentru input valid, input mai mare ca 5 si negativ
    {   if(newNoPlatforms>0 && newNoPlatforms <5)
        this->gameNoPlatforms = newNoPlatforms;
    else cout << "The number of platforms can't be negative and must be less than 5, since this is the maximum number of existing platforms." << endl;
    }

    void setGameNoSitesRating(int newNoSites) //testat pentru input valid, input negativ, input mai mare decat 15
    { if(newNoSites>0 && newNoSites<15)
        this->gameNoSitesRating = newNoSites;
    else cout << "The number of sites can't be negative nor greater than 15 since this is the maximum number of sites that our game is rated on." << endl;
    }

    void setGamePlatforms(string *newGamePlatforms, int newGameNoPlatforms) //testat pt input valid, returneaza adresa
    {
        if (this->gamePlatforms != NULL)
        {
            delete[] this->gamePlatforms;
        }
        if (newGameNoPlatforms > 0 ){


            this->gameNoPlatforms = newGameNoPlatforms;
            this->gamePlatforms = new string[this->gameNoPlatforms];
            for (int i = 0; i < this->gameNoPlatforms; i++)
            {
                this->gamePlatforms[i] = newGamePlatforms[i];
            }
        }
        else cout << "The number of new game platforms can't be negative. "<< endl;
    }
    void setGameRatings(int *newGameRatings, int newNoRatings) //testat pt valori valide, testat pt neNoRatings negativ;
    {
        if (newNoRatings < 0)
        cout << "The new number of sites that are rating the game can't be negative";


        else {
            if (this->gameRatings != NULL)
            {
                delete[] this->gameRatings;
            }

            this->gameNoSitesRating = newNoRatings;
            this->gameRatings = new int[this->gameNoSitesRating];
            for (int i = 0; i < this->gameNoSitesRating; i++)
            {
                this->gameRatings[i] = newGameRatings[i];
            }


        }

    }
    void setGamesSales(int *newSales)
    {
        if (newSales != NULL)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 19; i++)
            {
                gameSales[i] = newSales[i];

            }
        }
        else cout << "The sales can't be null." << endl;

    }

    void setLaucnhers(string *newLaunchers)
    {
        if (newLaunchers != NULL)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                gameLaunchers[i] = newLaunchers[i];
            }
        }
        else cout << "The name of the new launchers can't be null." << endl;
    }

//variabile static/const
    const int gameReleaseYear;
    static int noGames;

};

int Game::noGames = 0;
```

Comment: Please provide [mre]. As far as we can see: `setGamePlatforms` is not a member of `Game`. Hence, such example, shouldn't even compile.

Comment: I think you should use `std::vector<std::string>` for gamePlatforms. The getter will return a vector too, so you know the number of elements.

Comment: `g1.getGamePlatforms();` returns a pointer to string; hence the funny value which is an address. What were you trying to print?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i am editing it so i add the entire class so you can see it better.

Comment: @TobiasWollgam i am not allowed to use it since we didn't study it yet :(

Comment: @jignatius yeah, where is the mistake so it returns the values instead of the string ?

Comment: @DamianNarcis please edit your post again. Now it is not readable anymore.

Comment: @DamianNarcis I will repeat myself: Please provide [mre]. Did you read that link? One of the questions, you should ask, when providing it: "can everyone copy-paste this code block, to reproduce my problem?" The answer to that is: no, due to the fact, that we would need to remove bunch of extraneous symbols. If you want to provide comments in the code, you can do so with C++ comments (e.g. `//`).

Comment: @TobiasWollgam Im sorry im a disaster at editing and posting here, it's literally my first post ... my apologies ... but your code solved the problem ... thanks a lot and sorry for the eyes ache <3

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I am sorry, as i said it was literally my first post, Tobias's code sequenced solved it ... sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @DamianNarcis No offense, but to me, "this is my first post" is not an excuse. One should take the [tour], and read through [ask], and [help], **before** even asking. Those pages already instruct to provide [mre] in the question, when asking a question about the code.

Comment: Ok sir, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int Game::getNumberOfPlatforms() const
{
    return gameNoPlatforms;
}
```

And print them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < g1.getNumberOfPlatforms(); ++i)
    cout << g1.getGamePlatforms()[i] << endl;
```